# Snowflake Roles and Security

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

new to snowflake here, lets say I created snowflake **ROLE1**, and i grant user1 and user2 in the same role, now if that same role has the priviledge to write sql view in a shared schema, how do I prevent user1 to edit or delete the sql views created by user 2 and vice versa. do I need to create individual role for each user?

quick answer from experts here :)

Comment: You will need different roles in this case, as when using same role nothing will prevent your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You need to create two different roles with the required set of privileges, as the access control framework is based on roles.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/security-access-control-overview.html#overview-of-access-control